# Formatar Timestamp para string sem os milissegundos?

Tags: java, android

Tenho a seguinte variável `public Timestamp CreatedAt;`
Ela é colocada em um `textview` desta forma:

```
hora.setText(String.valueOf(notificacao.CreatedAt));
```

A saída é:

> 2017-06-29 12:31:21.759

Gostaria que fosse:

> 29/06/2017 12:31

Como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
try {
    Date date = formatter.parse(notificacao.CreatedAt);
    String data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(date);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar criar um método que faça a conversão, exemplo:

```
public static String convertDate(String mDate){

   SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
   try {
          Date newDate = inputFormat.parse(mDate);
          inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
          mDate = inputFormat.format(newDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return mDate;
}
```

Dessa forma, na hora de setar o TextView faça o seguinte:

```
hora.setText(convertDate(notificacao.CreatedAt));
```